Undefined reference building OpenCV via vcpkg C++
I'm trying to build an OpenCV project using vcpkg on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64, but I keep getting linker errors for "undefined reference" to multiple libraries. Examples:
/usr/bin/ld: vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lzma.c.o): in function `TIFFInitLZMA':
tif_lzma.c:(.text+0xd36): undefined reference to `lzma_lzma_preset'

/usr/bin/ld: vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/lib/libglib-2.0.a(gregex.c.o): in function `g_regex_get_string_number':
gregex.c:(.text+0x3357): undefined reference to `pcre2_substring_number_from_name_8'

/usr/bin/ld: gclosure.c:(.text+0x27bc): undefined reference to `ffi_type_pointer'

Do i have to find package and link to target for each one of those libraries that are basically dependencies of opencv? Shouldn't find package and target link open cv automatically do it for me?
My cmake list:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(MapEditor LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})



OpenCV and its dependencies must be  built correctly with vcpkg. Check if optional features like tiff, pcre2, and ffi are included, as your linker errors suggest those libraries are required.

@liaifat85 those dependencies are installed, example: build/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/lib/libffi.a but when invoking cmake --build build , this library is not included in the command
cmake --build build
[1/1] Linking CXX executable MapEditor
FAILED: MapEditor
: && /usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/MapEditor.dir/main.cpp.o -o MapEditor  -Wl,-rpath,/home/yen/repos/map_editor/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/lib  vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libopencv_calib3d4d.a  vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libopencv_core4d.a  (....many libraries but not libffi.a)

You should link to the opencv_core target rather than using variables, that'll also remove the need to do use include_directories

after changing to: target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE opencv_core)
i now have undefined references to cv::imread, cv::imwrite etc.

You'll need to link to all the targets that your code requires

so i have to link manually to all the dependencies of opencv? And all their dependencies too? Why would it even download every library that is marked as "dependency" if it doesn't link agaisnt it by default?

Not manually but using pkg_check_modules instead of find_package in cmake.

@3CxEZiVlQ find_package is the right approach for vcpkg libraries, pkg_check_modules would only be for os installed libraries

You don't have to link to the dependencies, the targets will do that for you but opencv is broken up into many components, you'll need to link to the target for each component that you use

I can't find the documentation for the list of modules but there is one in the Conan recipe https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/4622ac85d1cec8cb7a2fcc8a1796d4b73bff285e/recipes/opencv/4.x/conanfile.py#L487
